# Changing an audio/video file's metadata in Python

Tags: python, audio, metadata

Ok, I've searched around here but haven't found anything pointing to a solid answer.

I'm trying to change an audio/video file's artist, filename, rating, genre etc in windows, which shows up when you view folders in 'details'.

At the moment I have the files I wish to edit in a list and I am iterating through them, but as I said I am not sure how to change it for each file in the list.

```
def Files(The_FileList):
'''Changes each files metadata'''
for each_file in The_FileList:
    
    #clueless here.
    
return The_FileList
```

needs to work with .avi/.mkv general movie files as I do alot of encoding.

I'm looking for a simple option as this is all I want to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In many cases (and in this case), metadata is file-type specific.  (Some filesystems offer their own metadata, as NTFS and later do, but this particular metadata is coming from the file itself, and not from the filesystem).

To modify the metadata in the files in question, you *probably* can use the [Mutagen library](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen) (assuming these are mp3/aac/flac/vorbis/etc. - there are probably other audio formats that have a different metadata format).

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata/1.2.1 claims to handle both AVI and MKV, although I've never used it myself.  You could also check out the Kaa project (http://doc.freevo.org/2.0/Kaa).

Comment: Have you used these before? Had havok getting hachoir to install, and then I have not been able to find documentation and have no idea how to even import the file.

Then went to Kaa (for which most modules are only 70% complete) and have yet to find how to import it. Also its complaining about kaa.base being installed when I clearly did install it..
Any ideas here?

Comment: As far as I can tell hachoir mainly supports reading data from a variety of file formats.  It looks like there's now a binary file editor but there isn't a release version yet.  I'm unsure if the in-progress version supports editing.  I can't seem to find any python interfaces that support editing of mkv metadata.

Comment: the docs note *"... ID3 and APEv2 tags can be edited regardless of audio format. ..."* does Mutagen support **aac** tagging? cf ~ http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/

Answer (score 6):

Mutagen is actualized.

I leave an example for change 3 atributes of all the files in the directory:

```
import mutagen
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4
from os import scandir

ruta = './'
l_archivos = sorted([archivo.name for archivo in scandir(ruta) if archivo.is_file()])

mutagen.File(l_archivos[1])      # U: See the tags of the data

def edit_Media_Data():

    for f in range(len(l_archivos[:-1])):                 # A: A range of all the fields exept the script
        file = MP4(l_archivos[f])                         # A: Capture the file to edit
        file['©nam'] = l_archivos[f].replace('.mp4','')   # U: Take the file name and makeit the tittle
        file['©ART'] = 'Hector_Costa_Guzman'              # U: Edit the Autor
        file['©alb'] = 'Curso_Django'                     # U: Edit the Album
        file.pprint()
        file.save()
```

Comment: Possible to edit the promotion url and rating too?