# Edit MP4 metadata using Python

Tags: python

I need to give attributes (meta data) to a file in python code on Linux, specifically Ubuntu.

Specifically I need to set the author, title, album, etc. on MP4 files.

Comment: Who in their right mind voted to close this as off-topic?

Comment: Here is the aswer: [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300320/8635285)
Chekit out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try with [Mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen) or [Tagpy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tagpy)

Both seem very straightforward, but I don't have any experience with them.

Comment: @Meow Mutagen worked great for me editing mp4/m4v files, allowing me to give the files artwork and categorisation (adding the "stik" field). Everything worked great in iTunes afterwards. Can't comment on M4A files but thought they were a very similar container file type (either way it's not what the question asks).

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is ancient, but, If anyone is interested I put together some basic example python code.

I am focused on MP3s but going to expand it, just working on a custom MP3 Player with TKinter & Mutagen.

This example is strictly using Mutagen:
https://github.com/JayRizzo/MP3Player/blob/master/mp3TagEditor.py