# How to unpack a zip file without changing metadata?

Tags: python, archive, shutil

I’m using shutil.unpack_archive function to unpack a zip file, but it changes the “Date modified” attribute. 
How can I unpack an archive without changing the metadata of its content in Python?

Comment: Date Modified refers to when the file was modified, and that "modification" can be for any reason, such as opened the file, saved new content or in this case "unzip". I don't suppose there's an option to change the metadata., Here have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081444/changing-a-files-metadata-in-python

Comment: Do you mean the "Date modified" attribute of the archive file?

Comment: I meant the date modified of the content

Comment: Try using the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) module.

Comment: There's also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813243/extract-files-from-zip-file-and-retain-mod-date-python-2-7-1-on-windows-7) showing ways keep the modified timestamp.